# My apps crash due to hit backspace in inputfield due to afterTextChanged , how can i handle backspace for this code

Tags: java, android, android-textwatcher, addtextchangedlistener

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    String f = y.getText().toString();

    String[] data2 = f.split(" ");

    if (f.substring(f.length() - 1).equals(" ")) {
        StringBuilder M = new StringBuilder();
        String z = y.getText().toString();
        String[] data1 = z.split(" ");
        {
            String last = order(data1[data1.length - 1].toString());

            data1[data1.length - 1] = last.toString();

            for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {

                M.append(data1[i]);
                M.append(" ");

            }

            y.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            y.setText(M.toString());
            y.setSelection(y.getText().length());
            y.addTextChangedListener(this);

        }
    }
}
```

this is the code of my afterchangetext in this when the space is detected it changes the previous word to its standard form but when the user write something and trying to remove or hit backspace then apps crash due to this method please elp me how to handle backspace

Comment: post the crash log...

Comment: is it crash when edittext be empty ?

Comment: No when i trying to removing word i entered means on hit backspace

Comment: Exception dispatching finished signal.
04-09 05:52:07.572 2917-2917/com.example.mian.translatorapp E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
04-09 05:52:07.588 2917-2917/com.example.mian.translatorapp E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1      @rafsanahmad007

Comment: at which line?.....

Comment: @Elsunhoty yes it crash there is only one character is remaining in the input field ...due to java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 at this line 
   if (f.substring(f.length() - 1).equals(" "))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's crashing while edit text is empty because of using substring method on empty string.

`if (f.substring(f.length() - 1).equals(" ")) {`

Replace like this:

`if (f.length() > 0 && f.substring(f.length() - 1).equals(" ")) {`

Let me know if it's having issue.

Comment: If it's working for you, then please mark answer as correct. It helps others and me too.